# Adding a class to blocks in turn, when clicking on the button

Tags: javascript

I want the "active" class to be added to the "stick" block by clicking on the button, if you click on the button again, it will be added to the next "stick" block and so on until the end

```
<div class="media">
                    <div class="stick active"></div>
                    <div class="stick"></div>
                    <div class="stick"></div>
                    <div class="stick"></div>
                    <div class="stick"></div>
                </div>
                <button class="next">></button>
```

```
.media {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.stick {
    width: 6px;
    height: 16px;
    background: rgba(141, 50, 0, 0.1);
    border-radius: 20px;
    margin: 2px;
}

.active {
    height: 30px;
    background: #8D3200;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi so you're searching for something like this?: 
Note: i added id next to the button :)

```
const btn = document.getElementById(`next`);

btn.addEventListener(`click`, e => {
 document.querySelectorAll(`.media > .stick:not(.active)`)[0].classList += ` active`;
});
```

Comment: FWIW, you can use `document.querySelector(...)` if you want to get the first matching element.

Comment: and can you tell me how to make sure that the "active" class is removed from the previous element, I tried to find out the index of each element, and go through it through forEach, but writes to me undefined   @Dxg125

Comment: You have to remove it after adding the new "active" class.

document.querySelectorAll(`.media > .stick.active)`)[0].classList = classList.replace(`active`, ``);

Since we know the latter element is the newer.